# Как реализовать плавное изменение фонового изображения. Сплавное приближение и затем смена на новое

Tags: background

Очень надо реализовать во первых авто смену background хедера + плавное приближение (2 изображения постоянно меняются) и появление при смене изображения текста. 
Пример на данном сайте https://www.marelira.com/

Все это делать через animate ? Я начинающий

Comment: Для начала зумирование я сделал через @keyframes

Comment: .div {
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 600px;
 height: 500px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 background: url('bering-70.jpg')  no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;
     animation-duration: 6s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     animation-name: zooming; 
}

@keyframes zooming {
from {
 background-size: 100% 100%;}
to {background-size: 130% 130%;}
}